# Trying to import libraries on brython but the site sees them as .py files and not as folders with .py files

Tags: python, libraries, brython

I have a site on GitHub pages, and I'm trying to import libraries on `Brython`.

I have the project settled like this:

```
Project
   -index.html
   -brython.js
   -library1
       -__init__.py
       -file1.py
       -file2.py
       -...
    -library2
       -__init__.py
       -file1.py
       -file2.py
       -...
    -library3
       -__init__.py
       -file1.py
       -file2.py
       -..
```

I want to import all modules from the libraries, but if I use import when I go to the site console, it tells me it can't find the **init**.py file and that it can't find library1.py like it's trying to import a single module and not all of them.

I tried looking on internet but didn't find anything that could help me, I even used ChatGPT but it's useless.

I see that some says that it's impossible to import local libraries, but the official `Brython` site says, that I can, so I don't know, I'm really confused by the answers on the other questions.

Comment: HOW are you trying to import the libraries?  You haven't shown us any code at all.

Comment: import library1
but i tried more things chatgpt gave me and things i found online but none worked, like import .library1, using ____import____ instead of import, and many more

Answer (score 0):

According to [Brython documentation](https://brython.info/static_doc/3.12/en/file_or_http.html):

> The HTML files stored in a computer can be loaded in the browser in
> two different ways:
>
> - by the File / Open browser menu: in this case the browser uses the "file" protocol (the address in the address bar starts with `file://`)
> - by launching a local web server (for instance the one provided by Python standard distribution: `python -m http.server`) and entering the
>   file address in the browser address bar (for instance
>   `localhost:8000//app.html`). The protocol is "http" (or "https")
>
> These options are mostly the same, but **the "file" protocol comes with a few limitations**:
>
> - external scripts cannot be loaded with the syntax `<script type="text/python" src="test.py">`
> - **it is not possible to import modules or packages located in the same directory** as the application
>   files cannot be opened and read with open()
>
> The reason is that these features rely on Ajax calls to get the
> modules / packages source code, or the file contents; and browsers do
> not allow making Ajax calls when the protocol is "file".

(Emphasis mine.)

I recommend you try running something like `python -m http.server` in the `Projects` directory, and then opening `http://localhost:8000/index.html` in your browser`.

If that doesn't help, please edit your question to include additional information like error tracebacks, and how your code imports your `library` modules exactly.

Comment: I forgot you were using GitHub pages so my solution may not apply, in which case I would also ask for more precise information.